# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on loading jquery-min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I'm building a normal webpage which requires me to load about five CSS files and ten Javascript files.

- When loading them separately in the HTML page, my webpage loads fine.
- Now for production, I concatenated all the Javascript into a single file, in the order needed, and all the CSS into another file. But when I try to run the web page with the concatenated files it throws an error saying:

  `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

On the line where jquery.min.js is being loaded in the concatenated Javascript file.

What can I do to mitigate this? I want to concatenate all files and minify them for production. Please help.

**EDIT:** I merged the Javascript and CSS in the order they were when they were being loaded individually and were working fine.

Comment: how can we know what is `undefined` if you got no code to show?

Comment: the undefined is coming in the jquery-1.6.1.min.js that im loading.
maybe jquery is not being loaded properly or something?

Comment: I reckon this question isn't clear/narrow enough.  This is based on the fact that several of the answers are creeping out of the scope of the OP's question.  This page needs some TLC.  Either the question needs a clarifying edit, or these divergent answers need to be purged / moved somewhere else.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Assuming this problem still has not be resolved, a lot of individual files don't end their code with a semicolon. Most jQuery scripts end with `(jQuery)` and you need to have `(jQuery);`.

As separate files the script will load just fine but as one individual file you need the semicolons.

Comment: +1. When concatenating JavaScript code, you always should join them on semicolons. Too many of them are still valid, while to less lead to errors.

Comment: Bootstrap's js is one such example, apparently. Thanks for this! That was a real noodle scratcher.

Comment: I'm trying to import the youtube iframe API, and it doesn't end in a semicolon, and I'm getting this error. I'm not concatenating it with anything... I'm loading it with jQuery.getScript(). So... Could this be what's causing my error? Or does that not make sense?

Comment: Can someone explain what does this mean? I am just importing JQUery, Bootstrap and a file that I wrote and all are terminated by semicolon. So what is giving the error?

Comment: @Dustin - thank you so much for this.  i was going crazy trying to figure out why javascript that i minify+cat for production was broken.  the stock JS console errors would never suggest this, but sure enough... thanks!

Comment: OMFG! This problem has been driving crazy.  I thought it had something to do with function and variable hoisting in Javascript.

Comment: How do we resolve this if we see this error while working with a library? I am trying to use 2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js and /1.4.6/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js

Answer (score 28):

You might have to re-check the order in which you are merging the files,
it should be something like:

1. jquery.min.js
2. jquery-ui.js
3. any third party plugins you loading
4. your custom JS

Comment: its like this only
json2.js, jquery-1.6.1.min.js, jquery plugins, my code
.
its in this order.

Comment: if json2.js is using any jquery function, than jquery.min.js should be first.

i would suggest.

jquery.min.js, jqueryPlugins, json2.js, my code.

Answer (score 20):

This solution worked for me

```
    ;(function($){
        // your code
    })(jQuery);
```

Move your code inside the closure and use $ instead of jQuery

I found the above solution in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33348/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-when-using-a-jquery-plugin-in-ma

after seraching too much

Answer (score 16):

I got the same error from having two references to different versions of jQuery.

In my master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And also on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem recently with the [jQuery Validation plug-in](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation), using [Squishit](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt), also getting the js error:

> "undefined is not a function"

I fixed it by changing the reference to the **unminified** jquery.validate.js file, rather than jquery.validate.min.js.

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(
    @SquishIt.Framework.Bundle.JavaScript()
        .Add("~/Scripts/Libraries/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")
        .Add("~/Scripts/Libraries/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js")
        .Add("~/Scripts/Libraries/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
        .Add("~/Scripts/Libraries/jquery.validate.js")
        .Add("~/Scripts/Libraries/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
         ... more files
```

I think that the minified version of certain files, when further compressed using Squishit, for example, might in some cases not deal with missing semi-colons and the like, as @Dustin suggests, so you might have to experiment with which files you can doubly compress, and which you just leave to Squishit or whatever you're bundling with.

Comment: Using the unminified version was just the ticket for me - thanks.

Comment: For me it was the json2.min.js file from version 1.0.2 of a NuGet package which was causing the problem. I switched it to the non-min file and the Squishit combined file works fine now.

Answer (score 6):

For those out there who still couldn't fix this, I did so by changing my 'this' to '$(this)' when using jQuery.

E.G:

```
$('.icon').click(function() {
    this.fadeOut();
});
```

Fixed:

```
$('.icon').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I've run into the very same issue, when mistakenly named variable with the very same name, as function.

So this:

```
isLive = isLive(data);
```

failed, generating OP's mentioned error message.

Fix to this was as simple as changing above line to:

```
isItALive = isLive(data);
```

I don't know, how much does it helps in this situation, but I decided to put this answer for others looking for a solution for similar problems.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, i also I fixed it changing in the js libraries to the unminified.

For example, in the  tag, change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.rcarousel.min.js"></script>
```

For:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.rcarousel.js"></script>
```

Quiting the 'min' as unminified.

Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

### Remember: Javascript functions are CASE SENSITIVE.

I had a case where I'm pretty sure that my code would run smoothly. But still, got an error and I checked the *Javascript console* of Google Chrome to check what it is.

My error line is

```
opt.SetAttribute("value",values[a]);
```

And got the same error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Nothing seems wrong with the code above but it was not running. I troubleshoot for almost an hour and then compared it with my other running code. My error is that it was set to `SetAttribute`, which should be `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

In case there are any morons out there like me, I had this frustrating problem because I forgot a simple

`new`

keyword before instantiating a new object.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same message with the following code (in IcedCoffeeScript):

```
f = (err,cb) ->
  cb null, true

await f defer err, res
console.log err if err
```

This seemed to me like regular ICS code. I unfolded the await-defer construct to regular CoffeeScript:

```
f (err,res) ->
  console.log err if err
```

What really happend was that I tried to pass 1 callback function( with 2 parameters ) to function `f` expecting two parameters, effectively not setting `cb` inside `f`, which the compiler correctly reported as `undefined is not a function`.

The mistake happened because I blindly pasted callback-style boilerplate code. `f` doesn't need an `err` parameter passed into it, thus should simply be:

```
f = (cb) ->
  cb null, true
f (err,res) ->
  console.log err if err
```

In the general case, I'd recommend to double-check function signatures and invocations for matching arities. The call-stack in the error message should be able to provide helpful hints.

In your special case, I recommend looking for function definitions appearing twice in the merged file, with different signatures, or assignments to global variables holding functions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have commented out any commentaries. Sometimes when copying and pasting you will leave out the "/*!"

Also when you go into the console they will list your errors and you should take it one at a time. If you see "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token * " That might mean it is reading your js file and it isn't getting past the first line.

/*!
 * jquery.tools 1.1.2 - The missing UI library for the Web
 *
 * [tools.tabs-1.0.4, tools.tooltip-1.1.2, tools.scrollable-1.1.2, tools.overlay-1.1.2, tools.expose-1.0.5]
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Tero Piirainen
 * http://flowplayer.org/tools/
 * File generated: Wed Oct 07 09:40:16 GMT 2009
 */

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I accidentally passed too many parameters into a jquery function that only expected one callback parameter.

For others troubleshooting: make sure you check all your jquery function calls for extra parameters.