# Timepicker : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've got some trubble with this plugin : https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker
//= require admin/fileupload
//= require admin/category
//= require admin/cars
//= require admin/restaurants
//= require admin/events
//= require zipcodes
```

in admin/events.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.timepicker').timepicker();
});
```

And I got this error :
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Can anybody help me ?

EDIT :

Here is what I got with console.log($) :

```
function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    } VM13723:2
undefined
```

Comment: Have you included bootstrap-timepicker.js?

Comment: Yes
// require bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker
is a déclaration of bootstrap-timepicker.js (in RoR)

Comment: is your element `$('.timepicker')` loaded with ajax ?

Comment: What if you just do `console.log($)` or `console.log(jQuery)` ?

Comment: What version is your JQuery?

Comment: Don't write your `$('.timepicker').timepicker();` in `document.ready` function. Simply do it in normal function `$(function() { time-picker-call });`

Comment: Here is my version of jQuery 1.11.0

Comment: @Ranjith Ain't `$(function(){...})` just a shortcut ?

Comment: @f00bar : right. Normally, include all `script` files at `footer` page. But in RoR included at first. May be, the browser search the `time-picker` class when its loaded.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LY2LP/
The plugin work here !!

Comment: Some of your js files may be plugins addition and might be declared inside a anonymous function such as `(function($){ ... }(jQuery));` but sometimes the semicolon is miss and this will raise the error you are talking about "`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`" when they get merged together. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I've solved it:
At the first you have to install jQuery UI by NuGet packege manager.
If you don't have it search about how to add "jQuery UI to ASP.NET MVC "
 
1- Go to "http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/"
   and select one of the timepickers.
2- Download the package (right click on js and css files and select 
   "save as link").
3- Drag and drop "(name of timepicker js file).js"  in script 
   folder in your project solution explorer.
4- Drag and drop "(name of timepicker css file).css"  in script 
   content\themes\base\ folder in your project solution explorer.
 
5- Go to "BundleConfig" and add (name of timepicker js file).js to 
your "~/bundles/jqueryui" and ether add (name of timepicker css file).css 
to "~/Content/themes/base/css"
I hope it work for you