# LazyLoad TYPO3 ver. 6.2.1 with Bootstrap 3 - using blank image in SRC tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading, typo3

I'm having trouble with LazyLoad, it so lazy that it dont show my images at all..

```
<img class="lazyload" alt="" 
data-small="fileadmin/introduction/images/WNF/rejsegarantifonden.JPG"
data-medium="fileadmin/introduction/images/WNF/rejsegarantifonden.JPG" 
data-large="fileadmin/introduction/images/WNF/rejsegarantifonden.JPG"
data-bigger="fileadmin/introduction/images/WNF/rejsegarantifonden.JPG"
data-src="fileadmin/introduction/images/WNF/rejsegarantifonden.JPG" 
src="typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/Images/blank.gif">
```

Can someone help with this issue, see right site in the main section, then u can see where the images need to be, but isent showed [WNF.dk](http://wnf.dk/golf-vinrejser.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` JS Error on your page. If it's not the issue itself, try fixing it first, as else, nothing will run.

[Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on loading jquery-min.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js) says that this error can appear when concatenating scripts. In noticed you have merged js (probably by scriptmerger). I would turn that off for developing anyway, and search for scripts that don't end with a `;` after `(jQuery)`.

Comment: Ps: here's another - paid - way to lazy load adapting images http://www.resrc.it/demos/lazyload