# Jquery dialog is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am trying to open asp.net mvc view in jquery dialog.

Here is my view from where i am trying to open dialog:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#my-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $('.modal').click(function () {
            $('#my-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="my-dialog"></div>

@Html.ActionLink("Add Question", "AddQuestionInPage", new { pageID = @ViewBag.PageID },new { @class = "modal" })
```

But it shows this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It show the error on this line:

```
$(this).dialog('open');
```

What is going wrong? why dialog is undefined as i have added jquery-ui file.
Plz guide me,
Thanx

Comment: What happens when you replace `this` with `#my-dialog`?

Comment: @ZippyV I tried to replace 'this' with '#my-dialog' but still it shows the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to open view in dialog by doing following things:

In Layout file I ordered the scripts in this way:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")"></script>
```

as Karsten suggested, thanx Karsten your answer really helped!

And i replaced the following line:

```
$(this).dialog('open');
```

with this:

```
$('#my-dialog').dialog();
```

as ZippyV suggested in comment. Thanx ZippyV it helped!
Thanx. .

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the things you will experience when you got somekind of a mismatch between the path to the jQuery library or the order of ordering the references to the libraries you got.

Take a look at this, im sure it might be helpful: [Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on loading jquery-min.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js)

Comment: scripts are loading in this order:
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>