# collection_select with select2 and bootstrap: undefined is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select2-rails, collection-select

In a Rails 4.1 app, I have a collection select that is loaded from a hash. I would like to use the select2 boostrap styling, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have included the **select2-rails** gem, and updated **application.js** and **application.css** as per the instructions.

```
gem 'select2-rails'

//= require select2

*= require select2
*= require select2-bootstrap
```

The collection_select is loaded from a constant on the model. I don't think this is especially relevant to the issue, but added it here in case it helps someone.

```
FLASHCARD_TYPE = {"verb" => "Verb Conjugation",
                "name" => "Word",
                "number" => "Number",
                "quiz" => "Quiz"}
```

Rails view

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :card_type, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <%= f.collection_select(:card_type, Flashcard::FLASHCARD_TYPE, :first, :last) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flashcard_card_type").select2();
});
```

The rendered html shows the select2 javascript, and the select shows as:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="flashcard_card_type">Card type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select id="flashcard_card_type" name="flashcard[card_type]">
         <option value="verb">Verb Conjugation</option>
         <option value="name">Word</option>
         <option value="number">Number</option>
         <option value="quiz">Quiz</option></select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can this to work properly?
In fact I would also like the option to have a site-wide default for all selects via class, then the ability to override styling by individual id.

I thought this would work as site-wide for all selects, but it also does nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").select2();
});
```

**EDIT**

As recommended by @San I checked the Javascript console, and got

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This the code it failed on

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flashcard_card_type").select2();
});
```

**EDIT 2**
Full application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-markdown
//= require select2
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flashcard_card_type").select2();
});
```

**EDIT 3**
jQuery is finding the element OK

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    debugger;
    console.log($("#flashcard_card_type"))
  $("#flashcard_card_type").select2();
});
```

log

```
 [select#flashcard_card_type, context: document, selector: "#flashcard_card_type",  jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…]
 0: select#flashcard_card_type
 context: document
 length: 1
 selector: "#flashcard_card_type"
 __proto__: Object[0]
```

**EDIT - What I have tried**

- removed turbolinks
- added the javascript to the page
- deleted cache, restarted rails

What I have found

- jQuery can find the tag
- The select2 library is loaded via the network tab in the js debugger

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check if there are any JavaScript errors in the console. Include them to the question, if there are.

Comment: Yes you are right. There are errors: I have added them to OP.

Comment: might be a problem with some earlier javascript on the page missing an ending semicolon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js

Comment: Have you wrapped the JavaScript code in `<script>...</script>` block?

Comment: @vee No it is not on the page: it is in the global application.js file

Comment: @vee you are correct. I have corrected the OP. My apologies for the error

Comment: @vee no not yet. Am working on it

Comment: @vee yes it is loaded and green

Comment: Can you try adding `require_self` after `require_tree .` in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`?  I haven't used `select2` in rails or elsewhere but it looks neat: http://jsfiddle.net/RMYJJ/

Comment: @vee thanks for your help. No it didn't work also. Added some notes to the OP

Comment: I'm sorry, I think that's as far as I can get to with the information.  That error would occur if `select2()` is not loaded but you've already verified that.  One last verification would be to open the `select2` file from the developer tools and to verify that it looks correct.  By the way, I deleted my previous comments as they were for verification purposes only.

Comment: @vee Thank you very much for all if your help, I really appreciate it. I suspect there is some type of conflict. I will take a break and look at it again later. Regards

Comment: @ardochhigh did you solve this situation? If so, could you add it as answer? I'm in a similar situation. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just wondering. Did you run `bundle install` after adding the `gem` to the `Gemfile`?

If you did, the last thing to check is to make sure `select2` JavaScript file is loading before your block to use it. Verify that by doing view source on the page and make sure `select2.js` is listed before `application.js` file (assuming you are in dev mode).

Comment: thank you very much. I will check the order of js on the page this evening. Thanks for your continued consideration on this issue. PS: yes bundle install has been run numerous times.