# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Owl carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using:

- wordpress site
- owl carousel plugin

Here is the JQuery code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-images").owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979,2],
      itemsTablet : [768,1],
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : false,
      autoPlay : true,
      autoHeight: true
    }); 

  });

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-videos").owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979,2],
      itemsTablet : [768,1],
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : false,
      autoPlay : true,
      autoHeight: true
    }); 

  });
```

I've read that wordpress conflits with jquery in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js) question but I even changed to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#owl-images").owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979,2],
      itemsTablet : [768,1],
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : false,
      autoPlay : true,
      autoHeight: true
    }); 

  });

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#owl-videos").owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979,2],
      itemsTablet : [768,1],
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : false,
      autoPlay : true,
      autoHeight: true
    }); 

  });
```

But still not working, still getting

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: We need head part of your html code ?

Comment: Please make sure you included jquery library file and jquery library loaded after your plugin owlCarousel loaded

Comment: check if `owlCarousel` is loaded by running this in console `jQuery.fn.owlCarousel`

Comment: @JqueryKing shouldn't I load Jquery library before load owlCarousel? 
I've been doing this way and never had a problem.

Comment: @CerlinBoss 
jQuery.fn.owlCarousel
undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which means your plugin is not included

include the below things in the same priority order

1. jQuery
2. owlCarousel

Also make sure that the script links are not giving `404`

Answer (score 6):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#owl-images").owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979,2],
      itemsTablet : [768,1],
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : false,
      autoPlay : true,
      autoHeight: true
    }); 
  });

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#owl-videos").owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979,2],
      itemsTablet : [768,1],
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : false,
      autoPlay : true,
      autoHeight: true
    }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer comes a little late, but I hope it helps others.

1. see the js changes below

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#owl-images").owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979,2],
      itemsTablet : [768,1],
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : false,
      autoPlay : true,
      autoHeight: true
    }); 
  });

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#owl-videos").owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979,2],
      itemsTablet : [768,1],
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : false,
      autoPlay : true,
      autoHeight: true
    }); 
  });
```

2. If making the change above alone doesn't work in your WordPress theme, call the owl.carousel.js or owl.carousel.min.js in the head section, not in the footer

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for contributing. Answers like this need a little more explanation. You should be explaining how and why the code you've given us fixes the OP's question, and what problem the OP was really having that you have no resolved. Thanks.