# chosen plugin doesn't work in partial view after publish

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-chosen

I'm puzzled with this problem and hoping someone can educate me with a detail explanation. I am using MVC and chosen plugin on a partial view. I have the chosen script loaded on my Index page to avoid multiple loads when I call the partial view multiple times from my Index page/view. Everything works as intended until I test my published code/application on the server to find that it only works locally but not after publish. Below is what I did to confirm the problem.

I added a simple drop-down to my partial view for testing

```
//My actual code
//@Html.ListBoxFor(m => Model.MyID, new MultiSelectList(Model.Test.OrderBy(o => o.MyCode), "MyID", "MyCode"), new { @class = "chosen-select", @multiple = "multiple", @id = "SpecialDropdown" })

//My test code
<select class="chosen" style="width:200px;">
    <option>Choose...</option>
    <option>jQuery</option>
    <option selected="selected">MooTools</option>
    <option>Prototype</option>
    <option>Dojo Toolkit</option>
</select>
```

and this in my Index page/view

```
//My actual code
//$(".chosen-select").chosen();

//My test code  
$(".chosen").chosen()
```

Result - The test code added on the same Index page and partial view work locally and after publish. When I commented the test code and un-comment my actual code, it only works locally but NOT after publish.

The only difference here is that I added the css class dynamically. I also view the html code to make sure that the class is present and it is there! Yet, I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function."

Is there anything special about adding css class dynamically? Timing issue? I have tried to put my chosen call in a document ready. It didn't help. :(

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js) may be causing the issue - can you confirm? To quote to OP *a lot of individual files don't end their code with a semicolon. Most jQuery scripts end with (jQuery) and you need to have (jQuery);*

Comment: OMG - i think you might hit the spot! give me a few minutes. I have to open each file and add the ; to the end. I'll be back with the result.

Comment: They all ended with ;

Comment: My test code works after publish. I think it might be something else. The only different is that I have the css class coded on the page whereas my actual css class is generated/added to the html

Comment: Try setting up the test code as a multiselect and see if it throws the error. eg `<select multiple id="SpecialDropdown" class="chosen-select" style="width:200px;">` It might help you determine where the error is being thrown.

Comment: @wahwahwah Thanks for the idea. I just tested with multiselect and it yields the same result. Localhost works, but not after publish.

Comment: On another note, I just added another test to make sure my css is there by doing this alert($(".chosen-select").length); Any other testing ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you post your script and css references? Also, have you tested this issue in both IE and Chrome? Is it possible that you are loading conflicting versions of your scripts or css? HTH :(

Comment: @wahwahwah I just managed to fix it but not sure what happened. Since the issue only happens when I publish the code. I went ahead and check the File Publish Options to delete everything on the server prior to publish. Now it works on localhost and server.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue only happens when I publish the code. I just managed to fix it by checking the File Publish Options to delete everything on the server prior to publish. Now it works on localhost and the server.