# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).(thefuntionname) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).(thefuntionname) is not a function

this is always the error i had in my website can someone help me.
its already under a `function({});`. what should I do?

and sometimes even if theres an error the code still runs right.

the error :
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).opacityrollover is not a function

the code:

> Blockquote

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

            var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
            $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li, div.navigation a.pageLink').opacityrollover({
                mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
                fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                exemptionSelector: '.selected'
            });



    });
```

> Blockquote

Comment: these will be the example

the error :
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).opacityrollover is not a function

the code:
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

                var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
                $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li, div.navigation a.pageLink').opacityrollover({
                    mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                    mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
                    fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                    exemptionSelector: '.selected'
                });
           

         
  });

Comment: That looks like a syntax error. Can you please add your code to the question.

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: try adding a semi-colon in front of the function (as pointed out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js)

Comment: Have you your opacityrollover loaded to your page? Check in console.

Comment: Beri - yep actually the function work okay..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a conflict

Replace the $ with jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            jQuery('div.content').css('display', 'block');

            var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
            jQuery('#thumbs ul.thumbs li, div.navigation a.pageLink').opacityrollover({
                mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
                fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                exemptionSelector: '.selected'
            });

    });
```

opacityrollover is not available by default in jQuery, you need to add that function from the below url
https://code.google.com/p/galleriffic/source/browse/trunk/jalbum-skin/res/jquery.opacityrollover.js?r=31

Comment: Yes opacityrollover is not an inbuilt function in jQuery you need to add the function
Check my updated answer